# Xamarin MVVM push user data to viewmodel

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

like the title says I want to give through the user information to my viewmodel, but the problem is that the viewmodel is registered as a dependency and I am binding its content to the xaml page itself. How do I send the user information to the viewmodel itself? 
Thank you!

Xaml.cs part:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Calendar : ContentPage
    {
        public Calendar(User user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            FileImageSource image = new FileImageSource
            {
                File = "calendar.png"
            };           
            Icon = image;// push user information to the ICalendarViewModel
            BindingContext = AppContainer.Container.Resolve<ICalendarViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface ICalendarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    }
```

Bootstrap part registering dependencies:

```
public class Bootstrap
    {
        public IContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            RegisterDependencies(containerBuilder);
            return containerBuilder.Build();
        }


        protected virtual void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<CalendarViewModel>()
                .As<ICalendarViewModel>()
                .SingleInstance();


        }
    }
```

CalendarViewModel: I do not know if this will help

```
public class CalendarViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICalendarViewModel
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        private CourseInformation _information;
        private ICourseInformationRepository _repository;

        public CalendarViewModel()
        {
            _repository = new CourseInformationRepository();
            LoadData();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CourseInformation> _courses;
        public ObservableCollection<CourseInformation> Courses
        {
            get
            {
                return _courses;
            }
            set
            {
                _courses = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Courses));
            }
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            try


{
            ObservableCollection<CourseInformation> CourseList = new ObservableCollection<CourseInformation>(_repository.GetAllCourseInformation());
            Courses = new ObservableCollection<CourseInformation>();
            DateTime date;          
            foreach (var course in CourseList)
            {
                string [] cour = course.Date.Split('/');
                cour[2] = "20" + cour[2];
                date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(cour[2]), Convert.ToInt32(cour[1]), Convert.ToInt32(cour[0]));
                if (date == DateTime.Now)//TESTING WITH TEST DATE, datetime.now
                {
                    if (course.FromTime.Length < 4)
                    {
                        course.FromTime = "0" + course.FromTime;
                    }
                    if (course.UntilTime.Length < 4)
                    {
                        course.UntilTime = "0" + course.UntilTime;
                    }
                    course.FromTime = course.FromTime.Insert(2, ":");
                    course.UntilTime = course.UntilTime.Insert(2, ":");
                    Courses.Add(course);
                }
            }               
        }
        catch (ServerUnavailableException e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Server is niet beschikbaar, ophalen van kalender is niet mogelijk.";
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Bootstrap binding in app.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppContainer.Container = new Bootstrap().CreateContainer();
            MainPage = new LoginView();         
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it the User object your are receiving in the constructor of Calendar page that you want to pass on to the Viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to comment (not enough reputation) on @LeRoy, use a framework. I would recommend FreshMVVM and you can pass objects into the ViewModel and even pass in Services. It makes it all nice and clean, and it just works.

Comment: Yes , I started using a framework and all my normal problems got solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Should not your CalendarViewModel viewModel contain **BindableBase** ?

```
public class CalendarViewModel : BindableBase, ViewModelBase, ICalendarViewModel
```

what framework are you using? prism, freshmvvm.

Your View and Viewmodel is normally automatically handled by the framework, all you need to do is register your page.

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Views.CalendarPage>();
```

Comment: In C# you can't have two base classes.

Comment: I am currently not using a framework, I use Autofac as nuget package for the IContainer in the bootstrap class. Via the bootstrap class I register the dependency and this code works like it should @LeRoy

Comment: @BrianM So Question has to do with Passing a service to your ViewModel ?